# binding list variable one after another

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-3.0

this is my class

```
public class Users
    {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public int Age { get; set; }
       public string Gender { get; set; }
       public string Country { get; set; }
    }
```

i am  defing an list variable

```
List<Users> myList = new List<Users>
```

i have  four  functions each  one  returing a  string array

```
{of  data content like, names, age, gender, country}
**functions names**
 FunNames();
 FunAge();
 Fungender();
 Funcountry();
```

now i need  to  bind  these  these  return values   of  all these  functions into  list one by one
like.

```
myList =FunNames();
myList =FunAge();
myList Fungender();
.....
```

hope my Question is clear.
any help  would be  great thank  you.

Comment: It is far from clear what the overall objective is. Why do you want to reassign `myList` several times in a row? It makes no sense to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to do what you require as far as I know. You have to iterate all of those arrays, generate the Users instances and add them to your list.

```
string[] names = FunNames();
string[] ages = FunAge();
string[] genders = Fungender();
string[] countries = FunCountry();

/* have to make sure they are not of different lengths */

int minLength = names.Length;

if (ages.Length < minLength)
    minLength = ages.Length;

if (genders.Length < minLength)
    minLength = genders.Length;

if (countries.Length < minLength)
    minLength = countries.Length;

for(int i=0 ; i < minLength; i++)
{
    Users item = new Users();
    item.Name = names[i];
    item.Age = int.Parse(ages[i]);
    item.Gender = genders[i];
    item.Country = countries[i];

    myList.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, `FunNames()` *et al* each return a *portion* of the `Users` object.  This can make your problem a little bit difficult because the data for each part of the `Users` object is stored in a separate array.  Can we assume that each array is of the same length and that the corresponding positions in each array combine to make the various properties in the `Users` object? If so, we can use code like this:

```
public List<Users> GetUsersList()
{
    List<Users> myList = new List<Users>();
    string[] names = FunNames();
    string[] ages = FunAge();
    string[] genders = Fungender();
    string[] countries = Funcountry();

    for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
    {
        Users user = new Users();
        user.Name = names[i];
        user.Age = names[i];
        user.Gender = names[i];
        user.Country = names[i];
        myList.Add(user);
    }

    return myList();
}
```

The above code will iterate through each of arrays of strings returned by your functions and subsequently populate `Users` object and add them to the list.  Again, this assumes that your arrays "line up" and have the same length.

*NOTE: You may consider changing the name of `Users` to `User`.  Think about it: a `User` object tells the programmer to expect a single `User`, not multiple `User`s.  Your `myList` object represents multiple individual `User`s.*